Solutions for a Recurrence Relation: $a_n = -3a_{n-1} + 4a_{n-2}$
Question:
Which of the following is a solution of the recurrence relation $a_n = -3a_{n-1} + 4a_{n-2}$?

a. 2
b. 3
c. -1
d. 1

Attempt:
I have done the following calculations and arrived at this answer, but I am not sure whether it is correct. Kindly help.
To verify each option, we substitute them into the recurrence relation:

For $a_n = 2$:

Assume $a_{n-1} = 2$ and $a_{n-2} = 2$
$a_n = -3 \times 2 + 4 \times 2 = -6 + 8 = 2$


For $a_n = 3$:

Assume $a_{n-1} = 3$ and $a_{n-2} = 3$
$a_n = -3 \times 3 + 4 \times 3 = -9 + 12 = 3$


For $a_n = -1$:

Assume $a_{n-1} = -1$ and $a_{n-2} = -1$
$a_n = -3 \times (-1) + 4 \times (-1) = 3 - 4 = -1$


For $a_n = 1$:

Assume $a_{n-1} = 1$ and $a_{n-2} = 1$
$a_n = -3 \times 1 + 4 \times 1 = -3 + 4 = 1$



From these calculations, it seems that all the options (2, 3, -1, 1) satisfy the given recurrence relation. Hence, any of them could potentially be correct. I am looking for confirmation or correction of this conclusion.

If you imagine that the sequence is constant, $a_n=c$, the recursion becomes $c=-3c+4c$ which holds for all $c$ so any constant works.

The most general solution is $a_n=c+d(-4)^n$, but the choices of $c,,d$ are arbitrary.

From the question statement it looks like only one the option is correct. How do I solve it properly. It is obvious my method is not correct? If all were correct, there should have been option of 'all of these'

We can't usefully comment on the structure of the test question.  All constants are a solution to the recursion.  You don't need to check each case, once you know that $1$ is a solution, you can note that it's a linear recursion so any multiple of $1$ will also be a solution.

It's a practice test question for my upcoming exam. I am afraid if similiar question came then I won't be able to answer. I must know know how to solve it

You already know how to solve it, just hope that the exam doesn't have such mistakes.

The question is meaningless. I would assume it was intended to ask about the characteristic roots of the sequence. Then the answer is d).

Subtract $a_{n-1}$ for both LHS and RHS, you get $a_n - a_{n-1}=-4\times(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})$.  Although I completely do not understand the question, this might be helpful.
